# Refresh ReportViewer with new SQL data

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I have a website that uses a ReportViewer to display a SSRS serverside report. I also have controls/textboxes that are used to update the data behind using jQuery/AJAX. I want to try to avoid any page reloads.

I am now trying to refresh the ReportViewer after I have updated my data, without having the page reloaded. Unfortunately, I don't understand if there is a way to (re)load the new data into the ReportViewer. Using the refreshReport method in the ReportViewer control only rerenders with the old data.

Data gets updated with this code, the ReportViewer / report refreshes, but with the old data.

Can I get the new data from the database into the report without having some kind of page reload?

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SaveData() {
            var data = { text: $('#textBox').val() }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.aspx/SaveData",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {

                }
            });  
        }

        function OnSuccess(response) {
            var clientViewer = $find("MainReportViewer");

            if (clientViewer) {
                clientViewer.refreshReport();
            }
        }
     </script>

<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="MainReportViewer" runat="server" ProcessingMode="Remote" Width="100%" Height="100%" AsyncRendering="False" SizeToReportContent="True" ShowToolBar="False" ShowParameterPrompts="False">
                    <ServerReport ReportPath="/Rep/Rep" ReportServerUrl="http://localhost/reportserver" />
                </rsweb:ReportViewer>

<button id="SaveButton" name="SaveButton" type="button" onclick="SaveData()" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span>&nbsp;</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to make it work:

1. Use The Timer like **ASP.net Timer** and **JavaScript Timer**
2. refresh Data From Database every Tick and Use **Tick Event**
3. the Elapse Time Out then Your Data Reload **withOut Page Refresh**

Dude these steps definitely work.

any queries please ask in comments.

Comment: So how exactly would I "refresh data from database"?

Comment: I mean use ASP.net Timer and set tick event and write code in that event like inserting and select data from the database and More And If you Use Asp.net Timer Then You also Use ScriptManager and UpdatePanel in your Web application